# Move panel to the bottom in GNOME Shell 3.18.4

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

as the title says, how can I move the panel to the bottom? or even move the on left menu bar to the bottom in GNOME Shell 3.18.4
?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you call the panel. If you want to change the position of the top bar, you can install this extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/898/mmod-panel

Concerning the left menu bar (the Dash), you can install the Dash to Dock shell extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock

You can then configure both through the Gnome Tweak Tool, in the 'Extensions' tab, or through the web interface.